# Node.js require() returns nothing

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, require

I'm using CoffeeScript with Node.js on Windows 8. I have a directory with 2 files, main.coffee and test.coffee. The code in main.coffee is:

```
test = require "./test.coffee"
console.log test.x * 2
```

The code for test.coffee is:

```
x = 2
```

When I run `coffee main.coffee -n` I get back `NaN`. I've tried using parenthesis on `require` and `console.log` and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: you need to set the export value from your test.coffee file. Eg. `module.exports = { x: 2 }` will be `test.x //2`

Answer (score 2):

Node.js requires your modules to use `exports` to define what is exported from `require`

try test.coffee of:

```
exports.x = 2;
```